# Filters wort when using a counterflow

Tags: hops, wort-chiller

I'm building a counterflow chiller. But then I got to thinking how to filter the hops out of my wort. The last thing I want to do is clog the chiller with hops. I know I could use a hop bag. But does that work for 0 minute additions? Do I just switch to dry hopping? For what it's worth I use pellet hops.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and cheapest solution is to either use hop bags/socks or build a hop bag hanger which is also known as a hop spider and other names. Google for those and you'll find some simple, easy designs you can build with a quick trip to the hardware store.

If you have a Blichman kettle, you can try the Hop Blocker. Keep in mind that this is only designed for use with pellet hops (which you use anyways).

A bazooka screen is an option but not as easy to install and use as the others.

A false bottom in the kettle is a great option but only works with whole/leaf hops.

A hop back is an outstanding option but a bit more advanced as far as building one yourself and incorporating it into your system. The Blichmann Hop Rocket is a great product and works very well but runs about $140. A wort pump helps but isn't absolutely necessary depending on how well you can utilize gravity in your setup. Hop backs are designed for whole hop use and act as a very effective filter for trub, not to mention the amazing hop character achievable with one that you just can't get with simple whirlpool additions.

You can still use hops for a 0 minute/whirlpool addition with any of these methods.

Answer (score 1):

I also use a CFC and use whole hops with a false bottom in the BK.  If you want to keep using pellets, you could use a bazooka screen and whirlpool, but you'll leave more wort behind.